# URL Rewrite for links with differing numbers of query strings .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The site I am working on has a news section that shows the most current news article in the center of the page and a complete list of articles in the right sidebar.

I was able to create "pretty" links in my code that append the article title to the link, from:

`website.com/news.php?id=4`

to

`website.com/news/4/news-article-number-four`

Using this .htaccess code, I have been able to omit `www.` from the URL and also to remove the `.php` file extension from my pages and rewrite the URLs to serve up the proper news article:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# omit www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# rewrite pretty link to fetch news article
# was originally ^news/(\d+)/?$ added .* to allow the
# title to be ignored
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+)/?.*$ news.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

All of this works great, with much help from amazing people here on SO. Now the fun part.

At the top of the sidebar are two links, News Home and Featured News Items. The News Home link is a no brainer:

`<a href="news">News Home</a>`

which is internally redirected to:

`website.com/news`

in the above .htaccess code.

the Featured News Items link has a query string:

`<a href="news/featured/">Featured News Items</a>`

which I'd like to redirect to:

`news.php?type=featured`

I'm guessing that I need a separate rewrite rule for the Featured News Items link, I tried this but it did not work:

```
# test to add 'featured' in top sidebar link
RewriteRule ^news/(\w+)/?$ news.php?type=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

It seems as though this rewrite rule is colliding with the internal redirect or some such. This is all still a bit over my head.

Furthermore, I believe I'll need yet another rewrite rule for the Featured News Item sidebar links, something along these lines, but I can't test it yet because I can't seem to pass along the `type=featured` query string value:

```
# test to add 'featured' to sidebar links
RewriteRule ^news/(\w+)/(\d+)/?.*$ news.php?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

So the question is, do I have to have separate rewrite rules for the News Home, Featured News Items and sidebar links?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about redirect to same page, and inside this page you check if there's a specific new or not?

Way easier to solve...sometimes time it's more important than "the hard way".